# Data loss while using BufferedReader in java

Tags: java, java-8

Hi I was trying to read the file using BufferedReader in java when I compared the contents manually, I found there was data loss, I am using following code

```
private static String readFile(String filePath) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String data = "";
            while ((br.readLine()) != null) {
            data = data + br.readLine();
            }
            return data;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
            if (fr != null)
                fr.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return "Error : could not read the value";
}
```

my input filecontents are :- 
the happy bastard's quick movie review 
damn that y2k bug . 
it's got a head start in this movie starring jamie lee curtis and another baldwin brother ( william this time ) in a story regarding a crew of a tugboat that comes across a deserted russian tech ship that has a strangeness to it when they kick the power back on . 
little do they know the power within . . . 
going for the gore and bringing on a few action sequences here and there , virus still feels very empty , like a movie going for all flash and no substance . 
we don't know why the crew was really out in the middle of nowhere , we don't know the origin of what took over the ship ( just that a big pink flashy thing hit the mir ) , and , of course , we don't know why donald sutherland is stumbling around drunkenly throughout . 
here , it's just " hey , let's chase these people around with some robots " . 
the acting is below average , even from the likes of curtis . 
you're more likely to get a kick out of her work in halloween h20 . 
sutherland is wasted and baldwin , well , he's acting like a baldwin , of course . 
the real star here are stan winston's robot design , some schnazzy cgi , and the occasional good gore shot , like picking into someone's brain . 
so , if robots and body parts really turn you on , here's your movie . 
otherwise , it's pretty much a sunken ship of a movie .

While output is :-

damn that y2k bug . little do they know the power within . . . we don't know why the crew was really out in the middle of nowhere , we don't know the origin of what took over the ship ( just that a big pink flashy thing hit the mir ) , and , of course , we don't know why donald sutherland is stumbling around drunkenly throughout . the acting is below average , even from the likes of curtis . sutherland is wasted and baldwin , well , he's acting like a baldwin , of course . so , if robots and body parts really turn you on , here's your movie . null

Comment: Thank you -@Adi your answer helped me a lot to use my brain.

Comment: When you are using Java 8, you may replace your entire method with `return String.join("", Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath)));`.

Comment: Thanks -@Holger this is also very useful for the kind of utility I am planning to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is problematic. Note that you are reading line two times but using only one of them.. skipping every alternate line.

```
        while ((br.readLine()) != null) {
             data = data + br.readLine();
        }
```

Correct code would be.

```
        String line = null;            
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
              data = data + line;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to figure out the issue when @adi commented that I am not reading the file.

Comment: @DheerajSingh Good to hear that you are unstuck and moving ahead.